# Confluent Cloud - Generate Messages of Kafka Producer for Load Testing

Tags: apache-kafka, stress-testing, confluent-cloud

I have found many answers for load testing the on premise Kafka, but are there any ways to do it for Confluent Cloud Kafka?

We plan to stress test the consumers written in java+spring listening to topics from the producer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka-producer-perf-test` (or really, any tool) can use **any** Kafka cluster, cloud or on-prem, provided the respective producer properties.